# Unable to integrate function with several variables using Integrate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Consider a Gaussian wave packet coming from the left (for one-dimensional problem) with a positive momentum and encountering a step potential.  I would like to evaluate the transmitted scattered wave function.

The expression for the transmitted wave function is evaluating using the following integral(taken from this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.5179.pdf:

```
$Assumptions = k ∈ Reals && ℏ ∈ Reals && 
  k0 ∈ Reals && m > 0 && l0 > 0 && t > 0;

A0[l0_, k0_, k_] = ((2 l0^2)/π)^(1/4) (Exp[-l0^2 (k - k0)^2]);

T0[k_, κ_, d_] = (4 k^2 Sqrt[1 - Sign[v0] (k0/k)^2])/(
 (k + k Sqrt[1 - Sign[v0] (k0/k)^2])^2;

ψtr[l0_, k0_, v0_,m_, ℏ_, x_, t_] = 
 1/Sqrt[2 π]
   Integrate[
   A0[l0, k0, k]*Sqrt[T0[k, v0, k0]]*
    Exp[I (k x + Sign[v0] ( 
2 ArcTan[Sqrt[((k Sqrt[1 - Sign[v0] (k0/k)^2])/k)^
   Sign[v0]]] - \[Pi]/2) - (ℏ k^2 t)/(
        2 m))], {k, -∞, ∞}]
```

Is there any way to  get a closed form of the integral?

Comment: Are you even sure your integral has a closed form expression?

Comment: @J.M. I expect to have some expression as this is a well known problem in quantum mechanics.

Comment: Sure, but not all the well-known problems have closed form solutions. In any event, why not mention the "well-known problem" in your question for context?

Comment: @J.M. there is exactly the same expression (Eq. 7) in the following paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.6181

Comment: @J.M. I simplified further the expression but still don't get a closed form

Comment: Start by writing your equations using Mathematica. For example, `\pi` should be `\[Pi]`, `\kappa` should be `\[Kappa]`, `\hbar` should be `\[HBar]`, `\Psi` should be `\[CapitalPsi]`, `\infty` should be `\[Infinity]`, you cannot use `_` in a symbol name, and your parentheses/brackets are unbalanced.

Comment: @BobHanlon, I just wrote using mathematica.

Comment: I think @J.M. is right to wonder whether you can expect a closed-form expression for this. I would hazard that *most* problems in QM don't have analytic solutions. You can give Mathematica a fighting chance by adding `Assuming[l0 > 0 && k0 > 0 && k > 0 && v0 > 0 && m > 0 && \[HBar] > 0, Integrate[ ... ]]` but I think it's unlikely you'll get a closed-form expression.